# How to inject RoleManager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I need to inject RoleManager into Controller using Ninject in ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I am totally new in DI and Ninject, so I am not fully understand what Ninject do. I use Ninject 3.3.4, standard RoleManager from Identity 2.0 and EF6.2. My bindings are below:

```
public class NinjectRegistrations : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<HeroesContext>().ToSelf();
        Bind<IRepository<Hero>>().To<HeroRepository>();
        Bind<IRepository<Ability>>().To<AbilityRepository>();
        Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>().WithConstructorArgument("context", new HeroesContext());
        Bind<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>().ToSelf();
        Bind<HttpContextBase>().ToMethod(ctx => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)).InTransientScope();
        Bind<ApplicationSignInManager>().ToMethod(context =>
        {
            var cbase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
            return cbase.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        });
        Bind<ApplicationUserManager>().ToSelf();
        Bind<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>>().To<RoleStore<IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole>>();
        Bind<RoleManager<IdentityRole, string>>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

Before RoleManager I have successfully inject two repositories in HomeController, their work fine. Also I injected ApplicationUserManager in AdminController and AccountController and ApplicationSignInManager in AccountController, it seems their work fine too because I can log in. Current problem is connected with RoleManager, at first nothing worked at all. After some googling I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774803/ninject-and-asp-net-identity-2-0), it helped partly. Now when I try do get list of users using AdminController I get this and basic recommendations:

> Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating DbConnection
>
> No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>
> Activation path:
>
> 5) Injection of dependency DbConnection into parameter existingConnection of constructor of type DbContext
>
> 4) Injection of dependency DbContext into parameter context of constructor of type RoleStore{IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole}
>
> 3) Injection of dependency IRoleStore{IdentityRole, string} into parameter store of constructor of type RoleManager{IdentityRole, string}
>
> 2) Injection of dependency RoleManager{IdentityRole, string} into parameter roleManager of constructor of type AdminController
>
> 1) Request for AdminController

I tried to find solution, but found nothing useful. Below you can find code of AdminController's constructor, Application_Start() and context (I'm not sure it is needed). Please help, my hiring depends on this.

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public AdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<HeroesContext>(new DbInitializer());

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    var registrations = new NinjectRegistrations();
    var kernel = new StandardKernel(registrations);
    kernel.Unbind<ModelValidatorProvider>();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
}

public class HeroesContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Hero> Heroes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ability> Abilities { get; set; }

    public HeroesContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static HeroesContext Create()
    {
        return new HeroesContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Hero>().HasMany(n => n.Abilities)
                                   .WithRequired(n => n.Hero)
                                   .HasForeignKey(n => n.HeroId);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am totally new in DI". You should definitely start with [this introduction to DI](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition/chapter-1).

Comment: @Steven thanks for the book. I fought I need something like that to start to understand DI. Although big english materials are little difficult to me.

Comment: Note that this free chapter is only around 30 pages. Quite doable if you ask me. This will be well your time spent. And besides, if you don't read, how would you learn anything?

Comment: @Steven I mean it's often difficult to me to understand some important things and details. I read articles more often than books. Moreover there are a lot of things in books, that I will never use, but will spend time to understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your `RoleStore` class is expecting dependency of type `DbContext`. And since you don't have any binding to `DbContext`, Ninject falls back to implicit self-binding. That means it tries to create `DbContext` trough the constructor:

```
public DbContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
```

but before that it can't create `DbConnection` as explained in the message.

Solution is:

- change your binding: `Bind<DbContext>().To<HeroesContext>();`
- or change type of the dependency in `RoleStore` to`HeroesContext`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and explanation that the problem is. I have changed `Bind<HeroesContext>().ToSelf()` to `Bind<DbContext>().To<HeroesContext>()` and now controller works as it should.